# How I can loop my list2(may be create by random), when my list1 is equal to list2 print true

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

```
import random
from random import sample

list1=[]

your_number1= int(input("Input 1 number: "))
list1.append(your_number1)

your_number2= int(input("Input 2 number: "))
list1.append(your_number2)

your_number3= int(input("Input 3 number: "))
list1.append(your_number3)

your_number4= int(input("Input 4 number: "))
list1.append(your_number4)

your_number5= int(input("Input 5 number: "))
list1.append(your_number5)

your_number6= int(input("Input 6 number: "))
list1.append(your_number6)

print(list1)
```

the first list must be created by me

```
list2 = range(1, 50)
list2 = random.sample(list2, 6)
print(list2, "- random array ")
```

the second created by random and compare with first if  it is false, create one more time and compare, break loop when the list1 == list2

```
if len(list1) == len(list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i] == list2[i]:
            print("You win")
        else:
            print("You lose")
```

ALSO, I MUST COUNT HOW MANY DAYS NEED list2 to be equal to list1 
1 try it's 1 day

Comment: First of all: you don't need six variables if you don't use them, read the numbers with a loop. Additionally: what did you try already?

Comment: are you saying see if all of list1 == list2? if not regenerate list2 and compare again? right now you are checking element by element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `while` condition.

```
flag = True
while(flag):
  list2 = range(1, 50) 
  list2 = random.sample(list2, 6)
  if len(list1) == len(list2): 
    for i in range(len(list1)): 
      if list1[i] == list2[i]: 
        print("You win")
        flag = False
        break
     else: 
        print("You lose")
```

Comment: No indexing is necessary. Be prepared to be downvoted

Comment: @Pynchia.  No problem with down votes.  Could you please explain why no indexing is required.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you were looking for:

```
>>> import random
>>> list1 = range(1, 50)
>>> list1 = random.sample(list1, 6)
>>> list2 = range(1, 50)
>>> list2 = random.sample(list2, 6)
>>> for element1, element2 in zip(list1, list2):
        print("your number:\t{0}".format(element1))
        print("my number:\t{0}".format(element2))
        if element1==element2:
            print("You win")
            break
        else:
            print("You lose")
        print()

your number: 24
my number: 10
You lose

your number: 26
my number: 13
You lose

your number: 39
my number: 37
You lose

your number: 4
my number: 36
You lose

your number: 48
my number: 45
You lose

your number: 30
my number: 21
You lose
```